# Using iterative variable from C# for loop in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

On one of my pages I have a for loop to iterate through a list of "Projects" (which is the main model for my website) and display some of their data. The following code is nested in a table and the middle cells removed for redundancy.

```
foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubmissionNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
        <!-- and so on -->
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "DisplayDetails", new { id = item.ProjectID })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

The "Detail" link in the last cell will ideally make a box pop up (I'm thinking of using a Modal via Bootstrap) containing all of the data for the project. The "DisplayDetails" controller action returns a partial view that presents this information, but since I'm not using JavaScript or anything to render the partial view on the current page it renders it as it's own unformatted page. This is the controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DisplayDetails(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
    if (project == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return PartialView("~/Views/Projects/_Detail.cshtml", project);
}
```

Ideally I would pass the ID to the controller using AJAX like I did below (which is code from another page of my website, again edited to remove redudancy):

```
$("#show").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Projects/SearchTable',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            Line1: $('#' + '@Html.IdFor(m => m.Project.ProjectAddress.Line1)').val(),
            // and so on
            County: $('#' + '@Html.IdFor(m => m.Project.ProjectAddress.County)').val(),
        }
    }).done(function(partialViewResult) {
        $(".wrapper").html(partialViewResult);
        $(".wrapper").css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

And by doing this I can embed the partial view onto the current page instead of it opening as a new page. I'm just not sure how to pass the project ID for a specific row in the table as data to the controller. Is this even possible? If not is there another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your ActionLink with this:

```
<td><a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.ProjectID">Details</a></td>
```

Then,

```
$(".details").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var projectId = $(this).data('id');
    // Make the AJAX call here...
});
```

Comment: Actually before I saw your response I got it to work in a similar way. I changed the ActionLink to `<a href="#" onclick = "displayDetails(@item.ProjectID)">Details</a>` and then defined displayDetails the same way as I did the AJAX call in my post, but your solution seems like much cleaner code.

Comment: Yes, using jQuery is preferred over using inline click handler.